# Apache Nifi - files created in /tmp folder

Tags: ssl, apache-nifi, tmp

There are files that are appearing in the /tmp folder on some of our NiFi Linux hosts.  The files all begin with 'file', and they somewhat quickly fill up that folder (we have an automated job to keep that clear while we investigate the issue).  This started happening within the last 2-3 months.  I'm guessing that there may have been a .conf or a .properties files change, but no one has admitted to this.

We have tried stopping all processes in NiFi, but the files are still appearing.  We have also stopped NiFi entirely, and that did stop the files from being generated (which is leading me to believe something change in one of the .conf or .properties files), but the files began to be generated again when NiFi was restarted.

Perhaps coincidentally, I noticed that the nifi-bootstrap.log file on one of the hosts has this info generated about every second:

2023-07-18 00:00:04,757 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr javax.net.ssl|ALL|07 71 C5|membership datasource connection closer|2023-07-18 24:00:04.756 CDT|SSLSocketImpl.java:1055|Closing input stream
2023-07-18 00:00:04,765 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr javax.net.ssl|ALL|07 71 C6|membership datasource connection adder|2023-07-18 24:00:04.765 CDT|X509Authentication.java:246|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
2023-07-18 00:00:04,765 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr javax.net.ssl|ALL|07 71 C6|membership datasource connection adder|2023-07-18 24:00:04.765 CDT|X509Authentication.java:246|No X.509 cert selected for EC
2023-07-18 00:00:04,765 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr javax.net.ssl|ALL|07 71 C6|membership datasource connection adder|2023-07-18 24:00:04.765 CDT|X509Authentication.java:246|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
2023-07-18 00:00:04,765 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr javax.net.ssl|ALL|07 71 C6|membership datasource connection adder|2023-07-18 24:00:04.765 CDT|X509Authentication.java:246|No X.509 cert selected for EC
2023-07-18 00:00:04,765 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr javax.net.ssl|ALL|07 71 C6|membership datasource connection adder|2023-07-18 24:00:04.765 CDT|X509Authentication.java:246|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
2023-07-18 00:00:04,765 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr javax.net.ssl|ALL|07 71 C6|membership datasource connection adder|2023-07-18 24:00:04.765 CDT|X509Authentication.java:246|No X.509 cert selected for DSA
2023-07-18 00:00:04,765 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr javax.net.ssl|ALL|07 71 C6|membership datasource connection adder|2023-07-18 24:00:04.765 CDT|X509Authentication.java:246|No X.509 cert selected for EC
2023-07-18 00:00:04,766 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr javax.net.ssl|ALL|07 71 C6|membership datasource connection adder|2023-07-18 24:00:04.765 CDT|X509Authentication.java:246|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
2023-07-18 00:00:04,766 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr javax.net.ssl|ALL|07 71 C6|membership datasource connection adder|2023-07-18 24:00:04.766 CDT|X509Authentication.java:246|No X.509 cert selected for DSA
2023-07-18 00:00:04,766 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr javax.net.ssl|ALL|07 71 C6|membership datasource connection adder|2023-07-18 24:00:04.766 CDT|X509Authentication.java:246|No X.509 cert selected for EC
2023-07-18 00:00:04,766 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr javax.net.ssl|ALL|07 71 C6|membership datasource connection adder|2023-07-18 24:00:04.766 CDT|X509Authentication.java:246|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
2023-07-18 00:00:04,766 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr javax.net.ssl|ALL|07 71 C6|membership datasource connection adder|2023-07-18 24:00:04.766 CDT|X509Authentication.java:246|No X.509 cert selected for DSA
2023-07-18 00:00:04,766 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr javax.net.ssl|ALL|07 71 C6|membership datasource connection adder|2023-07-18 24:00:04.766 CDT|X509Authentication.java:246|No X.509 cert selected for EC
2023-07-18 00:00:09,327 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr javax.net.ssl|ALL|07 71 C5|membership datasource connection closer|2023-07-18 24:00:09.327 CDT|SSLSocketImpl.java:1245|Closing output stream
2023-07-18 00:00:09,327 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|07 71 C5|membership datasource connection closer|2023-07-18 24:00:09.327 CDT|SSLSocketImpl.java:572|duplex close of SSLSocket
2023-07-18 00:00:09,328 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|07 71 C5|membership datasource connection closer|2023-07-18 24:00:09.328 CDT|SSLSocketImpl.java:1656|close the underlying socket
2023-07-18 00:00:09,328 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|07 71 C5|membership datasource connection closer|2023-07-18 24:00:09.328 CDT|SSLSocketImpl.java:1675|close the SSL connection (initiative)
2023-07-18 00:00:09,328 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|07 71 C5|membership datasource connection closer|2023-07-18 24:00:09.328 CDT|SSLSocketImpl.java:754|close inbound of SSLSocket
2023-07-18 00:00:09,328 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr javax.net.ssl|WARNING|07 71 C5|membership datasource connection closer|2023-07-18 24:00:09.328 CDT|SSLSocketImpl.java:590|SSLSocket duplex close failed (
2023-07-18 00:00:09,328 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr "throwable" : {
2023-07-18 00:00:09,328 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr   java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
2023-07-18 00:00:09,328 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr     at java.base/java.net.Socket.shutdownInput(Socket.java:1539)
2023-07-18 00:00:09,328 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr     at java.base/sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.shutdownInput(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:218)
2023-07-18 00:00:09,328 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr     at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.shutdownInput(SSLSocketImpl.java:769)
2023-07-18 00:00:09,328 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr     at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.bruteForceCloseInput(SSLSocketImpl.java:719)
2023-07-18 00:00:09,328 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr     at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.duplexCloseOutput(SSLSocketImpl.java:655)
2023-07-18 00:00:09,328 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr     at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.close(SSLSocketImpl.java:579)
2023-07-18 00:00:09,328 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr     at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.close(SSLSocketImpl.java:1249)
2023-07-18 00:00:09,328 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr     at java.base/java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:188)
2023-07-18 00:00:09,328 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr     at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.close(PGStream.java:694)
2023-07-18 00:00:09,328 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr     at org.postgresql.core.QueryExecutorBase.close(QueryExecutorBase.java:155)
2023-07-18 00:00:09,328 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr     at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.close(PgConnection.java:743)
2023-07-18 00:00:09,328 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.quietlyCloseConnection(PoolBase.java:143)
2023-07-18 00:00:09,328 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.lambda$closeConnection$1(HikariPool.java:451)
2023-07-18 00:00:09,328 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
2023-07-18 00:00:09,328 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
2023-07-18 00:00:09,328 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)}
2023-07-18 00:00:09,328 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr
2023-07-18 00:00:09,328 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr )

Any ideas/suggestions?  I'm not a java/ssl expert, so please give lots of details for any suggestions.